# Buffer widening not working in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, buffers

I am using emacs 24.4 in Org-mode and try to narrow/widen to/from subtrees using <kbd>C-x n s</kbd> and <kbd>C-x n w</kbd>, repsectively. However Widening is not working and once I have narrowed down to a particular subtree I am stuck there until the next time I visit the file. I would appreciate any thoughts to resolve the issue.

PS: complete beginner here.

Solved: My bad; I failed to scroll up after widening, it was there, I just couldn't see it.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a recipe (preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)) to reproduce the problem, with a few more details.

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't it just a display issue when you are in the last portion of the file? After widening, try going to the buffer beginning (`M-<`).

Comment: @ Drew Thanks for contributing; choroba figured out my fault :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.

Isn't it just a display issue when you are in the last portion of the file? After widening, try going to the buffer beginning (<kbd>M-<</kbd>).

Comment: @ choroba, that was it! I was failing to scroll up to see the rest of it; I was testing the org-mode and didn't have any content past the narrowed subtree. This and auctex are pretty much the reason I started using emacs. Thank you so much!